# How can I use \MakeUppercase in \patchcmd without breaking hyperlinks?

Tags: table-of-contents

My university's thesis formatting requirements are such that chapter titles must be in all caps in the table of contents. So I used `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` macro to ensure that.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

However, doing this means that the chapter title no longer functions as a hyperlink. If I remove `\MakeUppercase`, the hyperlink works, but the chapter title is, predictably, no longer in uppercase. Is there a way I can automatically convert chapter titles to uppercase for the table of contents, but still have the hyperlinks work? I've seen similar questions asked, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply the answers in my case.

(Note that I am doing this with chapters, but the same behavior occurs with sections, subsections, etc. if the right commands are used, so it's not behavior specific to the book class or to the chapter command. But the formatting requirements don't extend to these, just chapters.)

Also, I'd like the titles in the bookmarks to be in title case, even with the titles in the TOC in uppercase if that's possible. So using `\chapter[BLAH]{Blah}` isn't ideal since that affects both TOC and the bookmarks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{} % uppercase but no hyperlink
%\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{#1}{}{} % hyperlink but no uppercase

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really patch like that, because `#1` stands for something like

```
\numberline{1}blah
```

and LaTeX gets thoroughly confused even if using an expandable version of `\MakeUppercase`.

You can instead patch `\@chapter` in the three places where it issues `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% an expandable version of \MakeUppercase
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \MakeUppercaseX \text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% patch \@chapter, in the hyperref version
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {{\thechapter}#1}
  {{\thechapter}\MakeUppercaseX{#1}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercaseX{#1}}}
  {}{} % uppercase but no hyperlink
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercaseX{#1}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to uppercase also the bookmarks (but I can't see why), then a slightly different approach can be used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% patch \@chapter, in the hyperref version
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {{\thechapter}#1}
  {{\thechapter}\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
  {}{} % uppercase but no hyperlink
\patchcmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
  {}{}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\MakeUppercase\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}
```

This will neutralize `\MakeUppercase` when making bookmarks.

Comment: This works great, thanks! Is it possible to do this without making the bookmark label all uppercase, though? Right now the changes affect both the ToC and the bookmark label. If possible, I'd like the chapters to not be all uppercase in the bookmarks (i.e., "blah" in the chapter and in the bookmarks, and "BLAH" in the ToC). If it's not possible to do this while retaining the hyperlinks I can live with it, but I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Jigsaw I provided the necessary change; on the other hand, why shouldn't the chapter titles be capitalized in the bookmarks, when they are in the TOC?

Comment: It’s simply an aesthetic preference. I’d really rather not capitalize the chapter titles in the TOC either, but it’s required there.

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with egreg's approach and looking into the details of `hyperref`, I discovered a solution that will affect the appearance of the chapter titles in only the table of contents, and won't affect the bookmark text. It uses his `\MakeUppercaseX` macro to modify `hyperref`'s `\contentsline` macro to convert the title to uppercase if the line is for a chapter, but not for other levels. Since `hyperref` adds the contents line after creating the bookmark, it doesn't affect the bookmark text.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% egreg's expandable \MakeUppercase
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \MakeUppercaseX \text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\contentsline}
    {\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend}
    {\in@{chapter}{#1}%
     \ifin@%
         \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname{\MakeUppercaseX{#2}}\hyper@linkend%
     \else%
         \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend%
     \fi}
    {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{blah}
\end{document}
```